# Task.Wait in UIThread is causing my UI to go crazy because locks don't work any more

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

The background:

I have some model which should give predictions once it is trained. The training has to be done only once - which is rather costly (few seconds). The predictions can then be done very fast.

The training is done implicitely when the first prediction is requested. Because I do not know how many models to be trained at startup time and training all at once is much faster than one by one.

My Problem:

When I am starting my training I am waiting for some tasks to finish. Now Windows is realizing that the UI thread is not busy an more and asking other controls if there is some paint to.

Now some other control also wants a model prediction. In my function I see that the training is not finished and start the training again. Result my function goes crazy - undefined behavior. A lock is of no use here because the second function call is from the same (UI) thread!

What makes it even more iteresting is that this is only an issue in Release mode without Visual Studio attached. So no chance of debugging. Only logging. Took me quite some time to figure out the problem...

```
    Start compiling on thread 1
     at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
     at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Compile()
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Evaluate(Double[] in_array)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModel.ScriptBulkEvaluate(DMyAppionary`2 dMyAppactor, Int32 dicCount)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModel.BulkEvaluate(DMyAppionary`2 dMyAppactor)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.MyAppModel.Evaluate(DMyAppionary`2 actuatorValues)
     at __Evaluate(MyCompModel* MyComp_model, Int32 regressor_index, uArray<double>* xvalues, uArray<double>* yvalues, uArray<double>* ylower, uArray<double>* yupper, uArray<int>* yvalues_inrange)
     at MyCompModel.MakePlot(MyCompModel* , Int32 regressor_index)
     at MyAppShell.UpdateCanvasPlots(MyAppShell* , OverlayInfo* ovi, PrintInfo* print_info)
     at MyAppShell.UpdateCanvas(MyAppShell* )
     at MyAppShell.Notify(MyAppShell* , XMEvent* ev)
     at XMWidget.SendEvent(XMWidget* , XMEventType et, XMMailbox* mb, Int32 info, Int32 info1, Int32 info2, Int32 info3)
     at XMDrawingArea.DoPaint(XMDrawingArea* , xmRect* rect)
     at XMDrawingArea.Message(XMDrawingArea* , MessageType type)
     at DrawingAreaWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
     at CallWindowProcA(IntPtr , HWND__* , UInt32 , UInt32 , Int32 )
     at XMDrawingAreaWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
     at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageA(MSG& msg)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
     at ecYaRlzjebO5lJJRJM.eAlVyhEdyCVdmimFqq.koonrpaTJfLI7QASS3()
     at ecYaRlzjebO5lJJRJM.eAlVyhEdyCVdmimFqq.e5ChpHZQl(Byte[] )
     at ecYaRlzjebO5lJJRJM.eAlVyhEdyCVdmimFqq.GetLicense(LicenseContext , Type , Object , Boolean )
     at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey)
     at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Scripting.Script..ctor(String source, ScriptLanguage language)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestEvaluation.BestModelScriptCompiler.PrepareCompilation()
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestEvaluation.BestModelScriptCompiler.CompileSynchronous()
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Compile()
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Evaluate(Double[] in_array)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModel.Evaluate(DMyAppionary`2 dMyAppactor)
     at MyComp.MyApp.Model.MyAppModel.Evaluate(DMyAppionary`2 actuatorValues)
     at __Evaluate(MyCompModel* MyComp_model, uArray<double>* xvalues, uArray<double>* yvalues, SByte* comment)
     at MyCompModel.MakePredMyAppion(MyCompModel* )
     at MyAppShell.UpdateCanvasPlots(MyAppShell* , OverlayInfo* ovi, PrintInfo* print_info)
     at MyAppShell.UpdateCanvas(MyAppShell* )
     at MyAppShell.Notify(MyAppShell* , XMEvent* ev)
     at XMWidget.SendEvent(XMWidget* , XMEventType et)
     at MyAppShell.UpdateTree(MyAppShell* )
     at MyAppShell.Notify(MyAppShell* , XMEvent* ev)
     at XMWidget.SendEvent(XMWidget* , XMEventType et, XMMailbox* mb, Int32 info, Int32 info1, Int32 info2, Int32 info3)
     at XMTreeView.SelectItem(XMTreeView* , uTreeNode* item, Int32 send_event)
     at XMTreeView.WMessage(XMTreeView* , WidgetMessage msg)
     at XMDrawingArea.DoInput(XMDrawingArea* , Void* m, Int32 had_focus)
     at XMDrawingArea.Message(XMDrawingArea* , MessageType type)
     at DrawingAreaWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
     at CallWindowProcA(IntPtr , HWND__* , UInt32 , UInt32 , Int32 )
     at XMDrawingAreaWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
     at DispatchMessageA(tagMSG* )
     at WinMain(HINSTANCE__* hInstance, HINSTANCE__* hPrevInstance, SByte* lpCmdLine, Int32 nCmdShow)
     at _WinMainCRTStartup()
```

My function is call from an outside application where I have no chance to change that to put the call in background worker.

```
    private bool Compile()
    {
        lock (compilerLock)
        {
            if (!isCompiled && CanCompile())
            {
                CompileSynchronous();
            }
        }
        return isCompiled;
    }
```

I already tried to do the work myself in background and put those calls in Tasks and wait for them. Now my application is waiting for itself forever. Because the second task is waiting for the first to complete. But the first cannot complete because the second is not done - thread and call stack are the same in the end.

I even tried to switch to "blocking" waiting for my task - to no avail...

```
        foreach (Task t in runningTasks)
        {
            try
            {
                while (t.IsCompleted == false) ;
                //t.Wait();
                t.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // some logging
            }
        }
```

I have no idea what else can be done...

**EDIT**

Running VS 2010 and .net 4.0

**EDIT No. 2**

To be more clear. My function should block. But it is called twice within the same thread. Even though the first call is not finished. Because it is the same thread locks are no good!

```
 at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Compile()
 ...
 at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageA(MSG& msg)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 ...
 at MyComp.MyApp.Model.BestModelEvaluator.Compile()
```

Comment: Seems like you have trouble bringing your calls in order. Perhaps some diagrams will help you here. The basic idea is still to do the work in background threads an let the ui thread do the ui things.

Comment: Instead of waiting on the task you probably should be adding a continuation.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I agree but as mentioned I have one entry point and no control about the UI thread (external app)

Comment: @juharr That seems interesting but I don't see how this can overcome my problem that the function is called twice within the UI

Comment: So, some UI is calling functionality you provide. And it is called twice, while the first calculation is not ready. So what is the desired behaviour? I would try some asynchronous approach with callbacks to the UI when the result is ready. Given that you can do all the work in the background and not block the UI, which should lead to a clearer separation of concerns and a more usable interface.

Comment: @MareInfinitus the desired behavior is that my call is blocking the current thread. And if some other thread is calling this function has to wait. But this is not possbile. Because more or less Function is called twice from the UI thread - even if the first is not finished yet. Please check the call stack and you will notice that Compile is calling Compile - more or less...

Comment: Instead of using locks, try upgrading to .Net 4.5 and using the async await keywords.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I am stuck with VS 2010 and .net 4.0. So not an option.

Comment: No, your function should *not* block.  You cannot block the UI like that.  (i.e. you get the symptoms you're complaining about).  If you have a task, when the task is done either via `await` or `ContinueWith` do what you need to do with the UI.  You will not be able to stop your UI from "going crazy" until you stop blocking it.

Comment: So the desired behaviour is blocking / synchronous call. So... you are done. Fine!     Amazing, this is not what I would expect.

Comment: @MareInfinitus What I want is easy yes. But in real life it is not that easy. My call is not allowed to be blocking by the OS! Check the call stack and you will notice that the message pump is calling (indirectly) that function again. And because it is the same thread a locks won't help!

Comment: @PeterRitchie Do you mean putting the compile in an own task and then wait for it? That could even work if I am waiting for the task several times in the same thread and could possible unwind my call stack... I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: No, I'm saying use a continuation--a callback that is called only *when* the task is completed.  You never *wait*.

Comment: @toATwork No, I never would say this is easy. It just seems a bit like a mess and simple things are just unclear. What do you deliver? What is the type of assembly. Perhaps I can describe a solution then.

Comment: @PeterRitchie my function is ment to be blocking. The application wants to have some model prediction to be drawn in a chart. If the external application asks for values from the UI thread, I must deliver. I do not see how I can use a continuation here?

Comment: @MareInfinitus you are correct, it is a mess. My library is called from an external application to get prediction values to be drawn in a chart. So that I can deliver predictions I must compile once. Compiling (C# code on the fly) is causing the message loop to run! Which then allows the application to draw again! This application is then calling (on the same thread) the prediction function again. Which see that compilation is not finished yet. As it is the same (UI) thread it can enter the lock, and compile again => undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the true problem!

We are encrypting our assemblies with a 3rd party tool. This tool adds a static constructor which is used for some license checking stuff.

Within that code, `Application.DoEvents()` is called several times which caused all my problems! See (encrypted) Stacktrace:

```
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
 at ecYaRlzjebO5lJJRJM.eAlVyhEdyCVdmimFqq.koonrpaTJfLI7QASS3()
```

Now on startup, I just create a dummy instance of my class. Suddenly all my problems are gone...

Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Can you provide more information on "dummy instance" please

Comment: @MareInfinitus I added a static constructor the first class which is instanciated. There I just say `new Script()`. This causes the static constructor of the script class to be run and perform the licensing stuff. Ugly, but gets the work done!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just have the `Compile` function return the current value of `isCompiled` if it's called a second time? So instead of blocking to obtain the lock, you *try* to take the lock, and return the current value of `isCompiled` if you can't. Like this:

```
private bool Compile()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(compilerLock))
    {
        // Lock already taken. There is a compile in progress.
        return isCompiled;
    }

    try
    {
        if (!isCompiled && CanCompile())
        {
            CompileSynchronous();
        }
        return isCompiled;
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(compilerLock);
    }
}
```

### Edit

I see now that you can't use `Monitor` because it allows re-entrant calls. You can use `Semaphore`, though.

```
private Semaphore CompileSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);
private bool Compile()
{
    if (!CompileSemaphore.WaitOne(0))
    {
        // Lock already taken. There is a compile in progress.
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        if (!isCompiled && CanCompile())
        {
            CompileSynchronous();
        }
        return isCompiled;
    }
    finally
    {
        CompileSemaphore.Releae();
    }
}
```

That will prevent re-entrant calls to `CompileSynchronous`, which should limit the problems. You can't block the thread on re-entrant calls, because it's the thread that's doing the compile. The best you can hope is that the second call sees the `false` return and ignores it.

The real problem, though, is that `CompileSynchronous` re-enters the message loop. That's going to cause you no end of trouble, and there's not much you can do about it except change the program so that can't happen. If you've designed the program so that it calls `DoEvents` (or otherwise re-enables the message loop), then you've created a huge problem for yourself and you need to re-think your design.

Comment: No. Not possible. Because then I cannot provide a value for the model prediction.

Comment: Even worse - Monitor.TryEnter is reentrant. That would change nothing at all because it is the same thread calling that function again.

Comment: @toATwork: How can a thread be doing a synchronous compile and at the same time be making a call to start *another* compile? For that to be possible, the `CompileSynchronous` method would have to be calling back to the UI, or executing what is in effect a `DoEvents` call.

Comment: That is exactly my problem - I did not know that myself either! If the call is from the UI Thread and you are waiting for a task. Windows is asking other controls if some painting needs to be done. Which leads to another call of my compile. Please check my stacktrace. You will see that Compile is calling Compile via some native message pump stuff!

Comment: @toATwork: You have a real mess on your hands. The real problem appears to be that the `Compile` method indirectly allows the message loop to be run, which apparently then lets you make a recursive call. Probably you need to set a flag of "compile in progress" and return `false` on subsequent calls. I'll add an edit to show how you can simulate that with a `Semaphore`. Whether that will help you is an open question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That mess took me a whole day... The message loop is run automatically because I am waiting for some tasks to finish. Thanks for your effort - I appreciate it! The compile in progress will most likely not help - because I need to return model predictions - which can only be done if the compilation is done.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I am afraid the semaphore is no good for me either. I do not call DoEvents. I am compiling some C# code on the fly - this is enabling the message loop, not my doing at all. Nevertheless is it my mess to cope with :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, then... you have a library.

This is a possible architectural solution to what I understand as your problem:

**Decouple calls to your library from calculations your library does**

You have to do at least two things to achive that.

***Decouple calls to your library from calculation***

This can be easily achieved by using a command pattern.
Every time your library gets called, take all information from the call, 
put it into one object, and put that object into some (concurrent) queue.

Start a thread to work on that queue, i.e. dequeue object from it and
perform your calculations (this can be on another thread, too).

You can find more information on the command pattern [here (as a starter)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

***Return values from your library***

This can be somewhat problematic. At least as you cannot immediately return
a valid result without blocking the UI thread for the first call. 
But blocking the UI thread is one of your major problems here.

I would suggest to return a null value at first. On subsequent calls, you
can return the latest result of your calculations.

I would store the latest result of your learning / trained results somewhere
near the UI thread so that you can return immediately after packing things
into the queue described above. The inital / starting value would be a
perfect match for a [null-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

***What is gained so far?***

Your calculations can be performed indepentently from the UI thread,
you can return instantly and always provide a sane value, and
multiple calls to your library are no longer a problem.

HTH